# Cadastro com Tabs

Tags: java, android

Senhores estou fazendo um cadastro e escolhi fazer usando Tabs porque o mesmo é extenso ( muitos campos ) e envolve fotos, desta forma eu consigo colocar as informações organizadas, é o cadastramento de ordem de serviço, no entanto observei que Tabs é 99% para apresentar dados não encontrei nenhum exemplo que mostre o seu uso em um cadastramento (no meu caso no sqlite) e agora com a tela feita como salvar/atualizar estes dados que estão nas abas?

Acredito que a logica seria obter o conteúdo das abas (3), para salvar um botão na ultima aba? sera que algum dos senhores já fez algo semelhante e possa me sugerir um caminho?

Procurei evoluir a rotina e agora tenho mais informações e códigos que possam exemplificar o que foi feito até então.

A lógica empregada para um cadastro com Tabs é que haverá um "ouvinte" na navegação, este ira acessar o fragment correspondente no viewPager e obter os dados para validação ou persistência.

Abaixo o ouvinte na atividade mãe, notem que o processo será feito obtendo o fragment da aba anterior

```
private void setupTabListener() {
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        View customView = tab.getCustomView();
        if (customView != null) {
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
            int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), android.R.color.white);
            icon.setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        }
    }
    // Aba Anterior
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onTabUnselected()" + tab.getPosition());
        View customView = tab.getCustomView();
        Boolean valido;
        // Obter o fragment usando o adapter
        if (tab.getPosition()==0){
           VeiculoFragment fragment = (VeiculoFragment)
                   .customFragmentPageAdapter
                   .getItem(tab.getPosition());
           // Na execução do método do fragment abaixo ocorre um erro  
           fragment.isValid();
        }

         }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
});
}
```

O Erro ocorre e capturei a pilha

```
     Process: br.com.tecnico, PID: 19927
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at br.com.tecnico.fragment.VeiculoFragment.isValid(VeiculoFragment.java:143)
 at br.com.tecnico.atividades.InstalacaoActivity$1.onTabUnselected(InstalacaoActivity.java:158)
 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.dispatchTabUnselected(TabLayout.java:1170)
 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1153)
 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1127)
 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1426)
 at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$TabView.performClick(TabLayout.java:1536)
```

A linha onde ocorre o erro é no fragment que foi instanciado e chamado o método isValid(), o erro ocorre no if(edtNumero.getText())

```
class VeiculoFragment extends BaseFragment {         
@Override
public boolean isValid() {
    // O Erro ocorre neste if abaixo
    if (edtNumero.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        //mostraSnackErro(getResources().getString(R.string.erro_frota_vazia));
        return false;
    }

    if (edtModelo.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
        //mostraSnackErro(getResources().getString(R.string.erro_modelo_vazio));
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Atualizei dando mais informações e códigos

Answer (score 1):

Para outros desenvolvam uma tela com Tabs e façam uso da mesma para um cadastro você precisará pegar os dados que estão nos fragmentos de cada Tab e esta não é uma tarefa fácil, eu passei uns dias para resolver a questão, perguntei aqui e ali, testei, fui na documentação de fragments, fiz o que ele sugere ou seja trabalhar com interfaces para enviar dados para a atividade mãe mais nada disto resolveria o meu caso em especifico.

Solução: Na Activity ter atributos privados de meus fragmentos, utilizar o adapter do ViewPager para criar as instancias já no onCreate, e fazer uso do listener do TabLayout para monitorar a mudança na Tab, qdo o usuário clicar na Tab seguinte salvar os dados da Tab anterior

Codigo da atividade

public class InstalacaoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = InstalacaoActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private CustomFragmentPageAdapter customFragmentPageAdapter;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabLayout tabLayout;

private int id;
private Fragment1 fragment1;
private Fragment2 fragment2;
private Fragment3 fragment3;
private Fragment4 fragment4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // outros 
    customFragmentPageAdapter = new CustomFragmentPageAdapter( getSupportFragmentManager(), getResources()
            .getStringArray(R.array.titles_tabs), this);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    //viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
    viewPager.setAdapter(customFragmentPageAdapter);
    //
    customFragmentPageAdapter.startUpdate(viewPager);
    fragment1 = (Fragment1) customFragmentPageAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, 0);
    fragment2 = (Fragment2) customFragmentPageAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, 1);
    fragment3 = (Fragment3) customFragmentPageAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, 2);
    fragment4 = (Fragment4) customFragmentPageAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, 3);
    customFragmentPageAdapter.finishUpdate(viewPager);
    //
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

// Aqui neste ouvinte vamos acessar o fragment
private void setupTabListener() {
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            View customView = tab.getCustomView();
            if (customView != null) {
                ImageView icon = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
                int tabIconColor = ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), android.R.color.white);
                icon.setColorFilter(tabIconColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            }
        }

        // Aqui qdo o usuário muda de tab vamos trabalhar e obter os dados
        // ou validar os dados da tab anterior
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onTabUnselected()" + tab.getPosition());
            View customView = tab.getCustomView();

            Boolean valido;

            //Fragment1 fragment1 = (Fragment1)
            //    customFragmentPageAdapter.getItem(tab.getPosition());
            // A linha acima ira dar o erro de NullPointer porque estou aqui criando uma nova instancia do fragement então aqui estava um grande problema que eu enfrentei  
            if (tab.getPosition()==0){
                if (fragment1 != null){
                    Log.i(TAG, "ver Validação dos dados");
                    valido = fragment1.isValid();
                    // Aqui estou chamando um metodo do fragmento 
                    // mais poderiamos obter os objetos da view e salvar 
                    // estes dados  
                    if(!valido){
                        Helper.displayInfoMessage(InstalacaoActivity.this,"Dados invalidos");
                    }
                }
```

Espero que isto ajude outros que venham a ter o mesmo problema ou que pretendam usar Tabs para compor um Cadastro e salvar os dados obtendo o conteúdo das diversas Tabs